# Share image by url in twitter

Tags: android, twitter4j

This is code

```
        StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(msg);
        twitter.updateStatus(status);
```

it work fine.
     but i want share my image by [url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NddFT.jpg)

please help me.

Comment: can you see my answer below, I use **twitter4j** too, I think it is working for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/22832422/1332870

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

1. Get the path of the image you wish to upload, if it is already on sd-card. If not then download it first, save to sd card and then get the path.
2. Then create a file using that filepath (`picFilePath`) as follows :

   ```
    File imgFile = new File(picFilePath);
   ```
3. Set this file as media in statusupdate object,

   ```
    // the txt message  
    StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(Msg);
    // set the image file as media with the message. 
    status.setMedia(imgFile);
   ```
4. Upload the message with image using an  AsyncTask

   ```
    twitter.updateStatus(status);
   ```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: What about tweeting with multiple images ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 T4JTwitterFunctions.postToTwitter
                (your_class.this.getApplicationContext(),your_class.this, twitter_consumer_key, twitter_consumer_secret, 
                Your_URL, new T4JTwitterFunctions.TwitterPostResponse() 
                { @Override public void OnResult(Boolean success) 
                    { 
                         if(success)
                         { 
                        //success
                         }
                         else
                         {
                        //not success
                         }
                    } 
                });
```

Comment: @user3492899 can you try this

Comment: I have a query. Can we discuss at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50550/discussion-between-ersin-gulbahar-and-suhail

Comment: Are you there I see ur msg now

Comment: I have posted a comment to your response.

Answer (score 0):

### I think this code will help you:

```
class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting Places JSON
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
        String status = args[0];
        try {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

            // Access Token 
            String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
            // Access Token Secret
            String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");
            System.out.println(access_token+access_token_secret+"....."+PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN);
            AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);


            StatusUpdate ad=new StatusUpdate("mala ruparel...........");



                // The InputStream opens the resourceId and sends it to the buffer
                InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.f1);

                ad.setMedia("Malvika",is);
            // Update status
            twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(ad);




            Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // Error in updating status
            Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog and show
     * the data in UI Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI
     * from background thread, otherwise you will get error
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                // Clearing EditText field
                txtUpdate.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: R.drawable.f1 is android image, but in my case only image url is availabel

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the help of the twitPic4j API. Just add the API for twitPic4j and write below code to upload the photo.

first you have to download the picture from url, save it to temp folder then upload it and after uploading delete this temporary image.

```
File picture = new File(APP_FILE_PATH + "/"+filename+".jpg");  
// Create TwitPic object and allocate TwitPicResponse object 
TwitPic tpRequest = new TwitPic(TWITTER_NAME, TWITTER_PASSWORD); 
TwitPicResponse tpResponse = null;  
// Make request and handle exceptions                            
try {         
        tpResponse = tpRequest.uploadAndPost(picture, customMessageEditText.getText()+" http://www.twsbi.com/");

} 
catch (IOException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace(); 
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter valid username and password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} 
catch (TwitPicException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid username and password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter valid Username and Password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}  
// If we got a response back, print out response variables                               
if(tpResponse != null) {         
       tpResponse.dumpVars();
       System.out.println(tpResponse.getStatus());
       if(tpResponse.getStatus().equals("ok")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Photo posted on Twitter.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //picture.delete();
       }
 }
```

Comment: where i insert image url.

Comment: hey as i wrote you have to download it first. otherwise it will only share the link as a tweet. there are many samples out there to download and store a file for temporary use.